# Why running unsafeRunSync() twice breaks RT

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have following application that I could not figure it out, why running it twice it breaks RT:

```
val program = for {
  _ <- IO { println("Welcome to Scala!  What's your name?") }
  _ <- IO { println(s"Well hello, foo") }
} yield ()

program.unsafeRunSync()
program.unsafeRunSync()
```

I run it twice and got the same result twice, why it breaks RT?

Comment: Where did you get the notion that it breaks RT?

Comment: From https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/05/02/io-monad-for-cats.html and search for `The above will run program`.

Answer (score 6):

It's because `val a = program.unsafeRunSync(); val b = program.unsafeRunSync()` is not the same program as `val a = program.unsafeRunSync(); val b = a`. If an expression is RT then you can inline it or factor it out freely. You can't do that here.

Comment: Could you please make an example about `inline it or factor it out`? And why it is not the same?

Comment: The first is an inlining of the second; the second is a factoring of the first. They're not the same because the first prints 4 lines of text and the second prints 2 lines.

Comment: Could you please explain, what are `inlining` and `factoring`? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Inlining is replacing a reference to a variable with the right-hand side of its definition. Factoring out means removing duplicate code by saving the result of an expression in a variable and replacing every instance of that expression with a reference to that variable.